# No data posts by my Kotlin appliaction to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, android-studio, kotlin, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I made a Authorizing system with SMS which gets number of an application then makes account and with verify code it let user to login. the problem is that when I send data by Retrofit in Kotlin as POST ,it sends no data (None) to server and Django logs show that no data sent for it. I know my Django API is working truly because of that POSTMAN works with it but my Kotlin application doesn't. Here I used APIService "Kotlin Intrface" class like this you see as below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("v1/register/")
suspend fun RegisterRequest(
    @Field("mobile") mobile: String
):Response<Reply>
```

I expected to see in logs that data sends for server but it doesnt work.
Also maybe you say that it needs Header but no ,cuz of I tried to set header for it also its Register and doesn't need token or anything like this and there's no persmission for it in server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, after trying several type of posting data to Django ,now I could find it.
the worked way for this is using @Multipart annotation like this.

```
@Multipart
@POST("v1/register/")
suspend fun registerRequest(
    @Part("mobile") mobile: String
):Response<Reply>
```

so it sends data to Django RestFramework ,but if someone found the better way then share here, thanks!